# android bluetooth LE - Why does the onReadRemoteRssi not work?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi, gatt

I want to continual read the rssi after gatt is connected.code like this:

```
final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter
        .getRemoteDevice(address);
if (device == null) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
    return false;
}

mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
boolean readRssiFlag = mBluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi();
Log.i(TAG,"readRssiFlag: "+readRssiFlag);
```

the mGattCallback like this:

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        ....
        @Override
        public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
            Log.i(TAG,"rssi = " + rssi);
        }
        ...
    };
```

and onReadRemoteRssi does not work.
ple tell me how to modify the code, or other solutions to read the rssi!

Thanks for your advise!

Answer (score 4):

```
private mRssiTimer;
....
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback()
{
    @Override
   public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState)
   {
       if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED)
       {            
          TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
         {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
               mBluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi();
            }
         };
         mRssiTimer = new Timer();
         mRssiTimer.schedule(task, 1000, 1000);
      }
      else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED)
      {
         mRssiTimer.cancel();
      }
   }
  ....
}
```

Comment: This is something I had initially, but I preferred the simplicity of a request-callback cycle after a connection has been established. However, sometimes the rssi callback is never triggered after a successful read rssi operation, which stops the request cycle. This only happens when I use 2 devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
boolean readRssiFlag = mBluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi();
```

The problem is that you didn't wait until the connection state changes before calling readRemoteRssi. The earliest timing for the readRemoteRssi call is after you receive onConnectionStateChange with newState = 2 (connected).